# Chart with SQL as DataSource

Tags: c#, winforms, charts

I want to make a dinamic chart, put a search textbox and combobox will interact with query (example: select columns from tb_table where combobox.selecteditem = textbox.text) and the chart change with query,
i tried this

```
DataTable table = SQL("Select columns from tb_table where + "Combobox.SelectedItem+ "= " + Textbox.Text);

chart.DataSource = table;
```

so how i can make that ? 
*SQL is the class that does SQL COMMANDS

Comment: Always use parameters to avoid sql injection and formatting errors.

Comment: There is not enough information in this question to really answer it.

Comment: There are [many](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A3152130+chart+datasource) [examples](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A3152130+chart+databind) and also a great [MSDN page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/dd456766%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) about this. Many way actually; I usually bind not the chart but  Series.Points as this is tthe most powerful option. Show more abut what you want and we can actually help..

Answer (score -1):

You can try :

```
DataTable table = SQL("Select columns from tb_table where + "Combobox.SelectedItem+ "= " + Textbox.Text);

YourChart.Series[0].Points.AddXY("Columns", DT.Rows[0][0]);
```

Note:
Above example only take 1 value from the DT and only using 1 series, if you use more than 1 series or row, you can try use loop.

Comment: This is the opposite of what he asked.